# Why query not updated value but get initial value in Function with ExtReact

Tags: extreact

I have form fn

code here
#update code. I initialization

```
query = {
   field: '',
   email: '',
 }
```

not initialization url

```
export function HomePage() {
const [query, setQuery] = useState({
    field: '',
    email: '',
});
const handleChaneValue = (value) => {
// not received data on change
    console.log('query', query);
    setQuery({
        ...query,
        [value.sender.name]: value.newValue
    })
}
console.log('query2', query);
```

query2 received data on change

console.log('query2', query);

#Update code: I add

```
return (
    <div>
        <Container
            padding={10}
            platformConfig={{
                desktop: {
                    maxWidth: 400,
                }
            }}
        >
            <FormPanel
                padding={10}
                shadow
                defaults={{
                    errorTarget: 'under'
                }}
                margin="0 0 20 0"
                title="Using Validators"
            >
                <Textfield
                    required
                    label="Required Field"
                    requiredMessage="This field is required."
                    errorTarget="under"
                    name="field"
                    onChange={handleChaneValue}

                />
                <EmailField
                    label="Email"
                    validators="email"
                    errorTarget="under"
                    name="email"
                    onChange={(e) => handleChaneValue(e)}

                />
             <Urlfield
                    label="URL"
                    validators={{
                        type: 'url',
                        message: 'Website url example http://'
                    }}
                    errorTarget="under"
                    name="url"
                    onChange={handleChaneValue}

                />
                <Container layout="center">
                    <Button 
                      ui="confirm" 
                      text="BTN submit" 
                      handler={handleClick} 
                      style={{border: '1px solid black' }}/>
                </Container>
            </FormPanel>

        </Container>
    </div>
)
```

}
export default HomePage;

When I change value in TextField. Query is

```
query2: {field: 'abc'}
```

But i change value in Email field. Query is not give old value "{filed: 'abc'}" throught I use ES6 three dot.

```
query2 : {email: 'xyz'}
```

and Query in funciton always initialization

```
query: {}
```

image change value [image]

#Update image: when I change value Url. fn handleChangeValue get initialization query

query: {
field: '',
email: '',
}

does not value query updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here issues were you did not initialize the value of textfield and emailfield I updated code pls check now

```
export function HomePage() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState({
    field:'',
    email:''
  });
  const handleChaneValue = (value) => {
    // not received data on change
    console.log("query", query);
    setQuery({
      ...query,
      [value.sender.name]: value.newValue,
    });
  };
  console.log("query2", query);
  return (
    <div>
      <Container
        padding={10}
        platformConfig={{
          desktop: {
            maxWidth: 400,
          },
        }}
      >
        <FormPanel
          padding={10}
          shadow
          defaults={{
            errorTarget: "under",
          }}
          margin="0 0 20 0"
          title="Using Validators"
        >
          <Textfield
            required
            label="Required Field"
            requiredMessage="This field is required."
            errorTarget="under"
            name="field"
            onChange={handleChaneValue}
            value={query.field}
          />
          <EmailField
            label="Email"
            validators="email"
            errorTarget="under"
            name="email"
            value={query.email}
            onChange={handleChaneValue}
          />
          <Container layout="center">
            <Button
              ui="confirm"
              text="BTN submit"
              handler={handleClick}
              style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}
              
            />
          </Container>
        </FormPanel>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
export default HomePage;
```

Comment: I tried but it's not active. I use framework extreact.

Comment: @HoangLe here you put wrong text field it should be `TextField`

Comment: I tried. 

I am understanding the problem is that every time query initialize value  in function is run, it is always initialized to {} but not the updated query value. like the console.log image

Comment: @HoangLe it always displays {} bcz you console before update state pls put after update state

Comment: first onChange query been updated when set state. it is shown in console.log query2, 
However the next onchange query doesn't get the updated value, but gets the initial value. it is shown in console.log query

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem. I using framework ExtReact so when run function, states re-initialized initil value. To solve this problem you can useRef and refer here.
[enter link description here](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/7.4.0/guides/getting_started/using_functional_state_components.html)